# Searching IDE for ios in others OS

Tags: c++, objective-c

What IDE can use if I want to build a application in iOS? It is possible to use something similar to Mono or plugin in Eclipse?

Comment: In which language are you going to develop?

Comment: I prefer C++, but you provide me a comparison of performance between c + + and Objective C?

Comment: For ios if you do in obj-c it will be better, hundreds of dozens of API are there. You can make native app. No need to use phonegap or titanium. And c++ and obj-c are not much different.

Comment: ios is isolation on Mac OS?

Comment: You can create from java, jsp and use someother applications as mentioned above, but the best one is Xcode unde mac os.

Comment: @user1929959 What do you mean by "iOS being isolation"?

Comment: Also, don't worry about the IDE, really. It has little to nothing to do with the quality of your code and that of the resulting app. As long as you have a suitable, up-to-date toolchain and a text editor that supports writing C, C++, Objective-C and Makefiles with syntax highlighting, you don't miss anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this one

http://www.gnustep.org/

But the best one is always XCode.

Comment: gnustep doesn't allow code to be authored for iOS apps.

Comment: "the best one is always Xcode" isn't remotely true. With Apple's great stocks of available brilliance, I certainly wouldn't bet against it catching up with AppCode. But it's not even in the ballpark as yet.

Comment: @Cris : i agree with AppCode, But I prefer Xcode, may be a personal choice. :)

Comment: @Anoop:most iOS/Mac devs clearly share your choice. But whenever I spend a bit of time with Xcode it feels, well, primitive. It does so little, albeit prettily.

Answer (score 2):

I have been coding in [AppCode](http://www.jetbrains.com/objc/) for my last application and while it is for pay it is worth the money, I have not done any c++ using appcode, but most of the advanced ide functions for coding, refactoring, and suggestions work just better than in XCode